# Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 libapache2-mod-php5.6 NO PPA

Tags: apt, 16.04, apache2, php

**Problem description:**

My intention is to enable PHP5 on Xenial 16.04 for an Apache2-related project

I have compiled PHP v5.6 from official source and am currently trying to install package **libapache2-mod-php5.6** using https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/libapache2-mod-php5.6/5.6.18+dfsg-4ubuntu1

After attempting to resolve dependencies, I end up with **php5.6-common** from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/php5.6-common/5.6.18+dfsg-4ubuntu1 depending on **php-common**, however, after installing said **php-common** via **apt**, I keep getting following message:

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
      php5.6-common : Depends: php-common (>= 18~) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Do I also need some outdated version of **php-common**?

Should I also build **libapache2-mod-php5.6** from source (and if so, are there any code packages suited to compile properly on Xenial)?

**NOTE:** I am *NOT* supposed to use Ondrej's ppa due to company policy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916045/unmet-dependencies-in-sudo-apt-get-upgrade) is similar to your problem. So as written there, you could give

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

a try which is supposed to search and install unmet dependencies.